# Splitting a Column in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas and am struggling to split a column of data into two columns.  Of course, I would like to split on the '-' character.  I would like the resulting columns to be `'FICO.low'` and `'FICO.high'`.

```
loansData['FICO.Range'][0:5]

- 81174 --- 735-739
- 99592 --- 715-719
- 80059 --- 690-694
- 15825 --- 695-699
- 33182 --- 695-699

Name: FICO.Range, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `extract` (available in upcoming 0.13 release):

```
In [140]: s
Out[140]:
0    81174 --- 735-739
1    99592 --- 715-719
2    80059 --- 690-694
3    15825 --- 695-699
4    33182 --- 695-699
Name: column, dtype: object

In [141]: res = s.str.extract('(.+) --- (?P<FICO_low>.+)-(?P<FICO_high>.+)')

In [142]: res
Out[142]:
       0 FICO_low FICO_high
0  81174      735       739
1  99592      715       719
2  80059      690       694
3  15825      695       699
4  33182      695       699
```

In an older version of `pandas` you can do it like this:

```
In [22]: res = s.str.match('(.+) --- (.+)-(.+)')

In [23]: res
Out[23]:
0    (81174, 735, 739)
1    (99592, 715, 719)
2    (80059, 690, 694)
3    (15825, 695, 699)
4    (33182, 695, 699)
Name: column, dtype: object

In [24]: df = DataFrame(map(list, res.values), columns=[0, 'FICO_low', 'FICO_high'])

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
       0 FICO_low FICO_high
0  81174      735       739
1  99592      715       719
2  80059      690       694
3  15825      695       699
4  33182      695       699
```

If you *really* want the `'.'` back in the column names do:

```
In [28]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('_', '.') if isinstance(x, basestring) else x)
Out[28]:
       0 FICO.low FICO.high
0  81174      735       739
1  99592      715       719
2  80059      690       694
3  15825      695       699
4  33182      695       699
```

but then you can't tab complete them anymore :(

FYI I'm playing a bit fast and loose with my regular expressions here, you'll probably want to restrict the set of matched characters to numbers using `'\d+'` instead of `'.+'`.